# How to create a database level trigger for insert/update

Tags: mysql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, triggers

I am trying to create a Database level trigger .It should trigger if any update/insert/delete occurs in any (5 tables in my database) table.Is it possible write a trigger DB level instead of table level...?

Comment: I had created a table level trigger to achieve this functionality,But i need to implement it database level.

Comment: have you googled this. available on net

Comment: can u please send me the link..???

Comment: http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2085/sql-server-ddl-triggers-to-track-all-database-changes/
May this link helps you get an idea

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it's possible. From the [reference guide](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-trigger.html):

> A trigger is a named database object that is **associated with a table**, and that activates when a particular event occurs for the **table**...